# Get correct context from child custom element which displays in repeater loop. Aurelia

Tags: javascript, repeater, parent, aurelia, custom-element

I have parent template which has a repeater for child custom elements.

```html
<!-- users.html -->
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" repeat.for="user of users">
    <git-hub-user-card user.bind="user" edit-user.bind="editUser"></git-hub-user-card>
</div>
```

`editUser` is callback located in parent VM and i need to call it from my child custom element.

Here is my child custom component

```js
/*user.js*/
import {customElement, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

    @customElement('git-hub-user-card')
    export class GithubUser {

        @bindable editUser;
        @bindable user = {};

        bind(parentCtx) {
            this.$parentCtx = parentCtx;
        }
    }
```

and here is child template

```html
<!-- user.html -->
<div class="content">
   <p class="name" >${user.login}</p>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" click.delegate="editUser.call($parentCtx, $event, user)">Edit Name</a>
 </div>
```

So, i have passed callback function in child component by binding.

```html
<git-hub-user-card user.bind="user" edit-user.bind="editUser"></git-hub-user-card>
```

My first question: is it ok? Or there is some more neat approach to call callback from child component?

Then i have tried to get parent VM context in the child VM:

```js
bind(parentCtx) {
  this.$parentCtx = parentCtx;
}
```

and have tried to bound callback call to this context:

```html
<a click.delegate="editUser.call($parentCtx, $event, user)">Edit Name</a>
```

but `$parentCtx` is not correct in this case because of `repeat.for` in parent template. `$parentCtx` is equal to my GithubUser. How can i get the correct context for editUser in parent VM? Should i path it with bounding?

Comment: would it not make sense to move your editUser method into the VM for the <git-hub-user-card> view?

Comment: @weagle08 no it would not. i want to change user info in popup window. So i need only one popup which can switch content view. If i'll move this popup in child component i'll get a lot of instances of this edit window. So i think i should place this logic in parent component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `call` binding command in the `users.html` template. It will preserve the correct context/this when the method is invoked. Here's what that would look like:

**user.js**

```js
import {customElement, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('git-hub-user-card')
export class GithubUser {
  @bindable editUser;
  @bindable user;
}
```

**user.html**

```html
<div class="content">
  <p class="name" >${user.login}</p>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" click.delegate="editUser()">Edit Name</a>
</div>
```

**users.html**

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" repeat.for="user of users">
  <git-hub-user-card user.bind="user" edit-user.call="editUser(user)"></git-hub-user-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works for me. I should read the docks more careful.